# Embedding a PDF into a leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, pdf

I'm trying to embed a PDF document into a Leaflet map popup, so that the PDF displays within the popup balloon when the user clicks the map point.

I've attempted to place `<embed src="mypdf.pdf" width="500px" height="500px" />` into the leaflet popup wrapper elements, but the `<embed>` element does not show the content of the PDF, it is just blank.

However, I can take this same `<embed>` element and place it anywhere else on the web page, outside of the Leaflet popup element, and it shows the PDF file as expected - pointing to a problem specific to the popup.

Is there a reason why the `<embed>` tag is not working inside of a popup?

Comment: have you tried using the PDF as an image and embedding that way?

Comment: What is your environment? Did you check for errors in console? I tested it in Win7 with IE11, Firefox and Chrome and it works OK.

Comment: I'm working on Win10 in Firefox. I'm not seeing any errors in the console. Can you show the contents of your example popup's `<div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper">` element?

Comment: I tested also in Win10 with Edge, Firefox and Chrome. It worked. For IE11 I had to install Adobe Reader.My definition is simple: `var myMarker = L.marker([39.744, -105.0043]).bindPopup('<embed src="test.pdf" width="200px" height="200px" />'); myMarker.addTo(map);
`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve it based on the solution written by [@TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm) in the comment. In case someone else is looking for a solution in embedding a pdf file in the popup window on a leaflet map. Below is a complete sample code .

***PS remember to change the pdf url***. **-->**  **(src="/static/test.pdf" width="200px" height="200px")**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="customstyle.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"

     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <title>TestMap</title>
</head>
<style>
    #map{height : 100vh;}
</style>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
</body>
<script>

var map = L.map('map').setView([ 51.5, -0.09], 5.5);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup. <br> <embed src="/static/test.pdf" width="200px" height="200px" />')


</script>
</html>
```